# Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS - Mouse removed and added intermittently

Tags: usb, xorg, mouse, gdm, udev

update: The same problem occurs in 20.10 with kernel 5.8.

I'm having a mouse hiccup that comes and goes where the mouse becomes unresponsive where the device is deleted and added again by UDEV. See log below.

There is another post where the keyboard and mouse was not detected at all, and that post suggested reinstalling the OS anew, but there must be a proper solution to this issue without reinstalling.

A clue to this problem might be: `okt 21 15:12:37 trillian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2808]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.`
But where can I check if there are multiple entries for this device?

```
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[205327]: (**) Option "fd" "109"
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[205327]: (II) event3  - Logitech Gaming Mouse G400: device removed
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[205327]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput" 
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[205327]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:67
gnome-shell[205444]: pushModal: invocation of begin_modal failed
kernel: usb 2-1.6: new full-speed USB device number 36 using ehci-pci 
kernel: usb 2-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c245, bcdDevice=69.00
kernel: usb 2-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
kernel: usb 2-1.6: Product: Gaming Mouse G400
kernel: usb 2-1.6: Manufacturer: Logitech
kernel: input: Logitech Gaming Mouse G400 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/0003:046D:C245.003C/input/input48
kernel: hid-generic 0003:046D:C245.003C: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech Gaming Mouse G400] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.6/input0
kernel: hid-generic 0003:046D:C245.003D: hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device [Logitech Gaming Mouse G400] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.6/input1
mtp-probe[782715]: checking bus 2, device 36: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6"
mtp-probe[782715]: bus: 2, device: 36 was not an MTP device 
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2808]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech Gaming Mouse G400 (/dev/input/mouse0) 
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2808]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2808]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[205327]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech Gaming Mouse G400 (/dev/input/mouse0) 
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[205327]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[205327]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2808]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech Gaming Mouse G400 (/dev/input/event3) 
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2808]: (**) Logitech Gaming Mouse G400: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2808]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech Gaming Mouse G400'
mtp-probe[782731]: checking bus 2, device 36: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6"
mtp-probe[782731]: bus: 2, device: 36 was not an MTP device 
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2808]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event3 13:67 fd 27 paused 1
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2808]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:67
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[205327]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech Gaming Mouse G400 (/dev/input/event3) 
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[205327]: (**) Logitech Gaming Mouse G400: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[205327]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech Gaming Mouse G400'
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[205327]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event3 13:67 fd 109 paused 0
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[205327]: (**) Logitech Gaming Mouse G400: always reports core events
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[205327]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[205327]: (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[205327]: (II) event3  - Logitech Gaming Mouse G400: is tagged by udev as: Mouse 
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[205327]: (II) event3  - Logitech Gaming Mouse G400: device set to 800 DPI
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[205327]: (II) event3  - Logitech Gaming Mouse G400: device is a pointer
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[205327]: (II) event3  - Logitech Gaming Mouse G400: device removed
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[205327]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/0003:046D:C245.003C/input/input48/event3"
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[205327]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech Gaming Mouse G400" (type: MOUSE, id 10)
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[205327]: (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[205327]: (**) Logitech Gaming Mouse G400: (accel) selected scheme none/0
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[205327]: (**) Logitech Gaming Mouse G400: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[205327]: (**) Logitech Gaming Mouse G400: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[205327]: (II) event3  - Logitech Gaming Mouse G400: is tagged by udev as: Mouse 
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[205327]: (II) event3  - Logitech Gaming Mouse G400: device set to 800 DPI
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[205327]: (II) event3  - Logitech Gaming Mouse G400: device is a pointer
```

From the log above this catches my eye in special:

```
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[205327]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech Gaming Mouse G400 (/dev/input/mouse0) 
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[205327]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[205327]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2808]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech Gaming Mouse G400 (/dev/input/event3)
```

It seems like the device is registered to two different devices at the same time: `/dev/input/mouse0` and `/dev/input/event3`.

Is it correct to assume that this is what causing the intermittent problems?

A new problem occurred now after the device was removed and added anew. The device stopped working at all, and the keyboard stopped working as well. The following error was spamming the journal:

```
kernel: usb 2-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 28 using ehci-pci
kernel: usb 2-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
kernel: usb 2-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 28 using ehci-pci
kernel: usb 2-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 28 using ehci-pci
kernel: usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/all, error -32
kernel: usb 2-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 28 using ehci-pci
kernel: usb 2-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 28 using ehci-pci
kernel: usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/all, error -32
[..]
```

To get the mouse and keyboard working again I had to unplug them from the USB jacks behind the computer and plugging them into my USB-Hub.

I have also tried to disable USB autosuspend by adding `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbcore.autosuspend=-1"`  to `/etc/default/grub` and verifying that autosuspend is disabled:

```
# cat /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend 
-1
```

The issue is similar as a bug reported back in 2018 and I have added comment showing the log output from the latest disconnect/connect and link to this post.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1794245

dmesg info:

```
 1870.524306] usb 2-1.4.2: USB disconnect, device number 16
[ 1870.901919] usb 2-1.4.2: new full-speed USB device number 17 using ehci-pci
[ 1871.497893] usb 2-1.4.2: device not accepting address 17, error -32
[ 1871.885903] usb 2-1.4.2: new full-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
[ 1872.097419] usb 2-1.4.2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c245, bcdDevice=69.00
[ 1872.097423] usb 2-1.4.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1872.097425] usb 2-1.4.2: Product: Gaming Mouse G400
[ 1872.097426] usb 2-1.4.2: Manufacturer: Logitech
[ 1872.099567] input: Logitech Gaming Mouse G400 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4.2/2-1.4.2:1.0/0003:046D:C245.0018/input/input30
[ 1872.158074] hid-generic 0003:046D:C245.0018: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech Gaming Mouse G400] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.4.2/input0
[ 1872.159609] hid-generic 0003:046D:C245.0019: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Device [Logitech Gaming Mouse G400] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.4.2/input1
[ 1872.572295] usb 2-1.4.2: USB disconnect, device number 18
[ 1872.961869] usb 2-1.4.2: new full-speed USB device number 19 using ehci-pci
[ 1873.173417] usb 2-1.4.2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c245, bcdDevice=69.00
[ 1873.173421] usb 2-1.4.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1873.173423] usb 2-1.4.2: Product: Gaming Mouse G400
[ 1873.173425] usb 2-1.4.2: Manufacturer: Logitech
[ 1873.175597] input: Logitech Gaming Mouse G400 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4.2/2-1.4.2:1.0/0003:046D:C245.001A/input/input31
[ 1873.234054] hid-generic 0003:046D:C245.001A: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech Gaming Mouse G400] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.4.2/input0
[ 1873.235454] hid-generic 0003:046D:C245.001B: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Device [Logitech Gaming Mouse G400] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.4.2/input1
```

Comment: I finally and very reluctantly decided to reinstall Ubuntu with only my keyboard and mouse plugged in and the issue still persists.

The device is still removed and added intermittently as the log above shows. There is a difference though; it isn't removed and added as often as before. But from what I'm experiencing i would classify this as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems not to be a software problem at all, and that the issue started when I installed Ubuntu over Fedora was merely a coincidence and not a problem with Ubuntu itself. According to the commentary on [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_L9Tv65gVYA), which explains how to disassemble the mouse:

> The thicker part of the cable located in the bend seems to always deteriorate far too quickly from use. But if you pull the cord in only a few centimeters so that a normal stretch of cord in within that bend the mouse will work fine and will not disconnect while in use.